# MySQL syntax error for date function

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a query which takes a pair of dates from user and searches whether it overlaps with any of the start and end column dates in my database table.

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$sql="select bikeid from bikebookings where date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $from))) <= end and date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $to))) >= start";
mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

I am getting an error as follows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', 20/03/2018))) <= end and date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' at line 1

Comment: Wow. You can't PHP and SQL like that.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You're just smashing things together here. Try formatting the values first, *then* put them in the database using `bind_param`.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry. I'm a beginner. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use use  mysql str_to_date function and for avoid sql injection. You should use binding param. For example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select bikeid from bikebookings 
     where str_to_date( ?, '%Y-%m-%d') <= end and  str_to_date( ?, '%Y-%m-%d') >= start");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$from, $to);
$stmt->execute();
```